# Looping queue with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I've got some very simple code below that I want to use as a starting point for a bigger jQuery solution. I need for the count() function to loop, but am not able to achieve this with the code below which only runs once and then stops. Would appreciate some pointers.

```
$(function() {
    count();
});

function count(){
    var $count = parseInt($("#count").text());
    $("#count").text($count).delay(2000).queue(function() {
        $(this).text($count+1);
        count();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call the next function in the queue, like this:

```
$(count);

function count(){
    var $count = parseInt($("#count").text());
    $("#count").text($count).delay(2000).queue(function(n) {
        $(this).text($count+1);
        count();
        n();
    });
}
```

[You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/aABfL/). Alternatively, you could replace `n()` with [`$(this).dequeue()`](http://api.jquery.com/dequeue/), either way works.  If it helps, you could also slim it down a bit, like this:

```
$(count);    
function count(){
    $("#count").delay(2000).queue(function(n) {
        count();
        $(this).text(function(i, t) { return parseInt(t, 10)+1; }).dequeue();
    });
}
```

[You can test that version here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/aABfL/1/).

Comment: Hey Nick, I have a follow on question with this problem - wondering if you might have any suggestions? Your answers are always the ones I find most well-explained and helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445843/jquery-preloading-images-for-animation