# jQuery Preloading images for animation

Tags: jquery

I know there are heaps of jQuery preloading threads, and I've read through most of them but still can't seem to find the solution to my problem.

I have a "stop motion" animation which is built via jQuery using queue and based on the sequential naming of images.  I don't want to run this animation until all the images required for it have been loaded. Spriting is not an option at the moment as there are different animations for different product types, and all the images have already been generated by the client.

My preload code at the moment is as below:

```
function preloadImages($img, $frames){
    var $imgsrc = $img.attr("src");
    var $getext = $imgsrc.split('.');
    var $ext = $getext[1];
    var $exploded = $getext[0].split('_');
    var $newsrc = "";
    for (var i=1; i <= $frames; i++){
        for (var j=0; j < $exploded.length-1; j++){
            $newsrc = $newsrc + $exploded[j] + "_";
        }
        $newsrc = $newsrc + i + "." + $ext;
        var image_preload = new Image();
        image_preload.src = $newsrc;
    }
}
```

Where frames is the number of total images in the sequence (6 or 12 at this stage), and the naming convention for images is as follows:

Brand_Product_Category_ProductID_SequenceNo.jpg.

What I'm trying to do is not load up the div holding the starting image until all of these images have been preloaded using the snippet below in document ready, but this doesn't seem to be working correctly, i.e., the holder is shown before all the required images have been preloaded, and consequently the animation doesn't run smoothly.

```
$(".holder").hide();
preloadImages($(".holder img"), 6);
$(".holder").fadeIn("slow");
```

I guess I need some sort of callback, though I'm not sure how to implement it.

Comment: What is the problem with your current code?

Comment: The holder is shown before the images are preloaded - edited my question to include this.

Comment: What is your naming convention? Why are you prefixing all variable names with the $ sign? (It's kind of confusing)

Comment: It's just the convention I use (comfortable with it, PHP developer, helps me identify variables quickly). Question updated to include naming convention.

Comment: You should work to adapt to different conventions better, it's really confusing to look at, because that's a very important sign in jquery.

Comment: At the very least, you might want to use `jQuery` instead of `$` if you're using `$` as a variable marker. However, @user257493 is right... a different convention would be better, especially if other people (which includes you in 6 months) are going to be looking at this code.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this:

When you assign a value to the `src` field of an `Image` object, it does just that: changes the `src` attribute. The browser still needs to load the image from wherever the `src` attribute points.

You can define a handler for the 'load' event of an Image... so you're going to need to use something along those lines.

One approach would be to define a list of images that need to be loaded. Each time an Image is loaded, set a flag in the array. Periodically, check the array and, once all the flags are set, indicating that all images are loaded, you can fade in your `div`.